# Adding a image to the multifield in CQ5 dialog?

Tags: javascript

Iam following according to the procedure providedin the link 
**"http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2013/12/aem-cq-56-adding-images-in-multifield.html"** and using the same js file for adding images to a multifield,but am getting an error of
**"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**.How can i clear the error and add the images to a multifield?

As the LOC is more am displaying the link,Please refer the link 
**http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2013/12/aem-cq-56-adding-images-in-multifield.html** for the js file.In link in **"imagemultifield.js"** file iam getting the error at the line number--13 as **"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**.

Comment: What line number is the error on? Can you show us the code you've written?

Comment: Thank you for reply..As the LOC is more am displaying the link,Please refer the link 
> **http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2013/12/aem-cq-56-adding-images-in-multifield.html** for the js file.In link in **"imagemultifield.js"** file iam getting the error at the line number--13 as **"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**.